# Copy directory, but fail if file already exists at destination

Tags: rsync, cp

`cp -a foo/* bar/` will copy the contents of foo into bar, replacing any files that already exist. I can use the -n flag to make `cp` not overwrite existing files or `-i` to make it ask interactively whether to overwrite files.

#### Questions

- Is there a way to make `cp` fail and return an error code if the file already exists?
- If not, is it possible to do with `rsync` or some other common tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Linux

It's possible to fail if a file exists on Linux, via a slight hack with GNU `nohup`. `nohup` redirects `/dev/null` to `stdin` so any interactive prompts are ignored, but treats the use of `stdin` as a failure.

```
$ nohup cp -ia foo/* bar/
```

To clean up a little bit:

```
$ nohup cp -ia foo/* bar/ 2>nohup.out && rm nohup.out || cat nohup.out
```

- By default `nohup` redirects `stdout` to `nohup.out` and `stderr` to `stdout`.
- `2>nohup.out` puts `stderr` into the file as well.
- The `&& rm || cat` will clean up on success or output the error from `nohup.out` on error. You can add whatever error handling you want instead of/including the `cat` or remove all of that and deal with `$?` as normal.
- You will need to be a bit smarter about the temp file location if you use this in earnest (`mktemp -d`)

#### BSD

On BSD you can redirect `stdin` to `cp` which will be treated as `n` and return a non 0 status.

```
$ cp -ia foo/* bar/ </dev/null
```

#### OSX

On OSX `cp` behaves differently to BSD, surprisingly, and does return a non 0 status with `-n` on a skipped file.

```
$ cp -n foo/* bar/
```